# Debian VM requires manually running "ifconfig eth0 up" to start network after reboot

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, debian-squeeze

I have a new guest install of Debian 6.0.2.1 i386 as a VM in VMware Server 2 Windows XP host. I selected only the "standard System Utilities." After that I installed SSH and VIM. I then changed the repository selection. Finally I ran `apt-get update` and rebooted the system. After the reboot the network card does not start automatically. To get it to work, I need to log into the console and type: `ifconfig eth0 up` once done I have full network access until I reboot, and then have to run the command again. After a rebuild, I was able to duplicate the problem. How do I get the network to start automatically?

Extra Info: `ifconfig` before running the fix only lists the local adapter. eth0 is missing from the output.

etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.15
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.254
```

/etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main

deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main
```

Comment: It is normal that `eth0` is missing from `ifconfig`'s output; the command only shows "up" interfaces. (Running `ip link` or `ifconfig -a` would list all.)

Comment: Also, unrelated to the problem, but IMHO you are configuring way more than necessary. `network` can safely be dropped -- it was only necessary in Linux 2.0, fifteen years ago. Similar for `broadcast`, which is automatically determined.

Comment: and yes, with -a it lists eth0 as expected. But until I run `ifconfig eth0 up` the network does not work. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: @grawity: so this is the weirdest thing. I don't see why it would hurt considering the [Debian docs]( http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_network_interface_with_the_static_ip) but I disabled those lines and it works. Should I post a bug report?

Comment: Yes, and do mention the reference page in it. (Since the IP address and netmask are always configured, both `network` and `broadcast` can be calculated in just two operations: network = addr & netmask; broadcast = addr | ~netmask; Having them configured explicitly will just result in confusion several weeks later.)

Comment: @rawity: if you create an answer responce, I will credit you... In this case, just say remove the Network and Broadcast lines from the file...